# ToolBar problem using Outlined text fields

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use an AppBar for my android studio project. In build gradle(module app) it implements :

```
com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07 [I use this because i want 
to use com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout on my xml/layout 
files],

com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3,

com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3,

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'.
```

In MainActivity.Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar1 = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
}
```

If I use 'toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_bar);' or 'setActionBar();'[setActionBar(Toolbar toolbar)] when I ran my app it crashs immediately.
I've looked for solution but always in the build gradle(module app) was implemented 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'.
And if I implement both of them my app crashs immediately

Can anyone help me to set my *toolbar1* as an ActionBar?

This is my xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity"

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/B_Back"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:onClick="startsSecondActivity"
        android:text="@string/B_Back_name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:text="@string/app_name" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks,
Sbert.

Comment: can i have a look to your xml files?

Comment: Yes, I have uploaded it in my question

Comment: You have no toolbar in your XML file, read Chris answer, it might be the right one. It that answer let you with more questions just ask that you don't understand

Answer (score 0):

```
Toolbar toolbar1 = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

Works only when you have added a toolbar in your xml files with id toolbar. If you want to retrieve the default toolbar use

```
getSupportActionBar();
```

I personally prefer to create my own toolbar if you want a code example of this just ask me or check this link https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up

Comment: To create the toolbar as you suggested my mainActivity (in the java file) should extend AppCompatActivity. So I should implement 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7'. And as I said in my question I can't implements both ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7' and 'com.google.android.material:material' [ which I use to be able to use com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout on my xml file]
files]).